# C# Database Displaying Relevant Data in Textboxes

Tags: c#

I'm stuck with something and I'd appreciate it if anyone can assist me.

I have a simple MS Access database that's linked to my program. The first thing I did was fill a combobox with one of the fields in my database ("Product Description").

What I'd like to do is when a user selects an item in the combobox, all the other fields in the record be displayed in text boxes.

```
string sConnection;
        sConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                        "Data Source=XYZDatabase.accdb";
        OleDbConnection dbConn;
        dbConn = new OleDbConnection(sConnection);
        dbConn.Open();
        cbxProducts.DisplayMember = "Product Description";
        dbConn.Close();
```

I've considered using possibly SQL or a DataReader, though I'm really not sure.
This is the event where I want the textboxes to be filled. I'm literally stuck here.

```
private void cbxProducts_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        txtProductNumber.Text = 
        txtProductDescription.Text = 
        txtProductCategory.Text = 
        txtProductCost.Text = 
    }
```

I hope I haven't formatted my question wrong or anything, apologies if I have, this is my first time posting here! Dx

Comment: on the index changed, you need to open another connection, and formulate an SQL query to select the fields you need from your DB, based on the selected value of the drop-down, and then fill those in the textboxes... you're going to need a OleDbDataReader to do this...

Comment: You can bind to a text box just like you have with the combo, just set source and member on each one. Or perhaps (you have some code missing), get ProductID from the SelectedItem of your combo, query that using a OleDbDataReader and simply assign them in method called from your event handler.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if your combo box is actually showing data from the DB.

In the first code block after

```
dbConn.Open()
```

and before

```
dbConn.Close()
```

you should have code like this:

```
SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("select prodid, proddesc from products", conn);
SqlDataReader reader;

reader = sc.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("prodid", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("proddesc", typeof(string));
dt.Load(reader);

cbxProducts.ValueMember = "prodid";
cbxProducts.DisplayMember = "proddesc";
cbxProducts.DataSource = dt;
```

And then in the second code block you need to fetch the selected Product ID first.

```
private void cbxProducts_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    string ID = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();

    //Based on ID make a sql query and fetch the details of that product from the DB. 
    //Follow the earlier code block to make DB connection and execute query.
    //Then populate the data in individual text boxes by looping through the dr.
    //I am leaving this deliberately for you to figure out and I am sure you can.

    txtProductNumber.Text = 
    txtProductDescription.Text = 
    txtProductCategory.Text = 
    txtProductCost.Text = 
}
```